# Problem withOccurrence of divisible numbers

Tags: java, arrays, exception

*Hello everyone !*

My program is not working how It is supposed to and I dont know why.
Thanks for any feedback.

**This is my task:**
Write the code that finds the number of array elements that are divisible by 8 in a given integer array of 10 elements specified at the input. The array elements are given one at a time, always in a new line.

**And this is my solution:**

import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaApp {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner vstup = new Scanner(System.in);
   int pole [] = new int [vstup.nextInt()];
   int i;
  
  for (i=0;i<pole.length;i++) {
    pole[i]=vstup.nextInt();
  } 
   int osem=0;
   for (i=0;i<pole.length;i++) {
    if (pole[i]%8==0) {
      osem++;    
    }
  }
 System.out.println(osem);
} }
```

Comment: what is the result you are getting?

Comment: Please show your compile time error/s. Thanks

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
 at JavaApp.main(JavaApp.java:10)

Comment: Do you have this issue in some online Java compiler?